# overflow:scroll doesn't fill div / changes div size

Tags: html, css, position, scrollbar

I have this code:

```html
<div style="position:absolute;left:0px;top:0px;width:17px;height:395px;background-color:white;border:1px solid black;">
<div style="position:inherit;;width:inherit;height:inherit;overflow:scroll;"></div>
<button style="position:absolute;left:0px;top:139px;width:17px;height:73px;background-color:white;border:1px solid black;"></button>
</div>
```

If you look at the generated HTML, you will see that there is a white square that is not filled by the scrollbar on the bottom. How does this happen? When I inspect the element, the overflow:scroll div does not have 395px, but 378px. When I correct it to 395px the scrollbar will fill the parent div visually, but there will be an overflow.

What is happening here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is simply the space for the **horizontal** scrollbar. You can make it visible by increasing your elements width:

```css
.bar {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  width: 80px;
  height: 395px;
  background-color: white;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.inner {
  position: inherit;
  width: inherit;
  height: inherit;
  overflow: scroll;
}

button {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  top: 139px;
  width: 17px;
  height: 73px;
  background-color: white;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="bar">
  <div class="inner"></div>
  <button></button>
</div>
```

You can avoid that space by using [`overflow-y`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow-y) instead of the more general `overflow`:

```css
.bar {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  width: 17px;
  height: 395px;
  background-color: white;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.inner {
  position: inherit;
  width: inherit;
  height: inherit;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

button {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  top: 139px;
  width: 17px;
  height: 73px;
  background-color: white;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="bar">
  <div class="inner"></div>
  <button></button>
</div>
```

In general it's a good idea to seperate styles from markup. It's easier to avoid problems if not using inline styles.

Comment: Thank you. I didn't think of the vertical scrollbar at all.
All the HTML and CSS is generated so I can't separate.

Comment: I see. Glad I could help!